# Audio Device, change Speaker setup

Tags: c++, delphi, winapi, api, audio

I want to change from my program the speaker setup, which is under speaker settings / advanced... section.

I tried to find maybe there is some sort of registry entry but no luck till now :|

Any Ideas ?

Thanks a lot !

Comment: What OS? There's quite a difference between XP/Vista/W7 audio stacks. The only constant is the absense of documented API for your task.

Comment: Right now I need it for XP, but eventually I will need to get it working with Vista/Win 7 too.
Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, here is the code for what I wanted

var
 ds:IDirectSound;
begin
  if DirectSoundCreate(nil, ds, nil) <> DS_OK then
    raise Exception.Create('Failed to create IDirectSound object');
  ds.SetSpeakerConfig(1);

Answer (score 1):

I found this old thread about people failing to do this under Vista.

- http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/windowspro-audiodevelopment/thread/187692f0-c71a-4317-98f9-77bcc6d67d08

It seems that it is possible using DirectSound using XP though and someone claims he managed to find a hacky way to do it under Vista.